# Sequelize Model Unit Test

Tags: node.js, testing, sequelize.js, sinon

I have a `User` sequelize model that has a `beforeCreate` hook that encrypts the password using `bcrypyt`. `Bcrypyt` is loaded as a dependency by the model using a `require` statement.

Now, I'm writing my tests for my models and I want to write a test that ensures `bcrypt` is hashing the password on create.

At the moment, I have added a setter onto the `User` model that sets the `bcrypt` object. In my tests, I can then create a spy using `sinon` and inject the spy using the setter and ensure it is called on create.

Is this the correct way to do it? I feel as if I'm creating a setter purely for my tests and that it serves no other purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to test is a point of religious debate in the development community. I'm of the opinion that as long as you *are* testing, exactly how that gets done is a matter of preference.
I tend to write tests that behave like my application as much as possible.

If you want to ensure that bcrypt is properly hashing the user password on create, then create a user, save it, and check the password.

This can be more work with making sure a test DB is running for the tests, but I find it provides good results. And the setup and teardown is very scriptable.

For this example, you don't even need a test framework to test this behaviour.

```
var User = require( './User' )
var BCRYPT_HASH_BEGINNING = '$2a$'
var TEST_PASSWORD = 'hello there'

User.create({ password: TEST_PASSWORD }).then( function( user ){
  if( !user ) throw new Error( 'User is null' )
  if( !user.password ) throw new Error( 'Password was not saved' )
  if( user.password === TEST_PASSWORD )
    throw new Error( 'Password is plaintext' )
  if( user.password.indexOf( BCRYPT_HASH_BEGINNING ) === -1 )
    throw new Error( 'Password was not encrypted' )
})
```

Comment: Except that that test will leave your database in a dirty state; you don't clean up after it.

Comment: @Jez `And the setup and teardown is very scriptable`

Comment: Until a test fails and the teardown can't run for some reason.

Comment: This is more an end to end test, making sure the object was really created, not whether it's available to the application. The unit test should be fast and not access the actual database.

Comment: THIS IS NOT UNIT TEST! you are connecting to DB in `require('/.User');`