# Sequelize unit testing with jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, sequelize.js

I'm currently creating a NodeJS / Angular / Sequelize case study project. So, I bootstraped the project with the yeoman angular generator, and use jasmine / karma for client-side unit testing.

Now that I'm on the server side, I, off course, want to do unit tests for it with the same framework, jasmine, thanks to jasmine-node and rewire.

But I'm relatively new to Sequelize.js, and I'm still trying to find the good way to do the unit testing for my models. Of course, I could do like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697494/sequelize-model-unit-test) recommend, but I'm worrying about consistency ...

So, how would you do unit tests, with jasmine-node and rewire, for Sequilize.js ?

For example, for a model :

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Client', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastname: DataTypes.STRING
  });
}
```

I know there is almost nothing to test here, but this is just for an example.

Comment: I have been trying to work out how to do the same but with jest instead of jasmine. So far I haven't had any success. Thus currently my models don't have any unit tests and i'm using functional tests instead with casperjs.

Comment: Thx, casperjs is in fact a good tool. Even if it's not helping at all for this case, i certainly will use it for other stuff ... For now, I just do my unit tests at a slightly higher level than models (of course, if my models are broken, this higher level breaks to, so ...). So, no solution for now ...